# Can I define how a browser displays an object?

Tags: javascript, browser, javascript-debugger

I have a LinkedList object I created. In the debugger (for javascript/typescript) I want it to display as an array to make it easy to go view any element. Is there a way to do this in IE, Chrome, Firefox, or Opera?

Answer (score 0):

you can make something like this:

```
var array = $.map(myObj, function(value, index) {
return [value];
});
```

This way you can set up your object as an array.

Comment: How does that change what is displayed for the object in the debugger?